# Is it possible to use revapi maven plugin to do check against a SNAPSHOT version?

Tags: maven, jenkins, revapi

I'm currently setting up revapi-maven-plugin for a project, using latest version (0.7.0), and we want to check on our jenkins that no regression appears in our API during development. 
Then for my process I don't want to check the regression between a snapshot and a release but between two snapshots.

Unfortunately (?) we use a different repository for our snapshots and our releases, and apparently revapi-maven-plugin seems not able to get the latest snapshot version from the snapshot repo.

Or is it and I did not understand how to do that?

I already put those value in my configuration but it does not change anything:

```
<alwaysCheckForReleaseVersion>false</alwaysCheckForReleaseVersion>
<oldVersion>LATEST</oldVersion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supported since the version `0.8.0` of the `revapi-maven-plugin`.
The documentation of the `oldVersion` property reads (https://revapi.org/modules/revapi-maven-plugin/check-mojo.html#oldVersion):

If you don't want to compare a different artifact than the one being built, specifying just the old version is simpler way of specifying the old artifact. The default value is "RELEASE" meaning that the old version is the last released version of the artifact being built (either remote or found locally (to account for artifacts installed into the local repo that are not available in some public remote repository)). The version of the compared artifact will be strictly older than the version of the new artifact. If you specify "LATEST", the old version will be resolved to the newest version available remotely, including snapshots (if found in one of the repositories active in the build). The version of the compared artifact will be either older or equal to the version of the new artifact in this case to account for comparing a locally built snapshot against the latest published snapshot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Let's continue the discussion on the [github issue](https://github.com/revapi/revapi/issues/54) for the feature.